# Click with selenium does not work on IE9 browser

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium

Using Selenium webdriver to test websites in an IE9 browser, the click does not work and no error is displayed.

What should I do?

Comment: what's the html element and if possible provide link to the webpage

Comment: No It's a website that is currently being developed. The html element is a span. I tried also to click on img and div elements but in vain.

Comment: Have you tried with Chrome and firefox?

Comment: Yes that works with Chrome, Firefox, IE 10 and IE11. The problem is with IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Then go with javacscript click. instead of selenium click

Comment: Try to click the parent element first. <element>.find_element_by_xpath("..").click() , then click the element again